# OracleBulkCopy throws triggers error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oracle11g

I am using `OracleBulkCopy` in c#. I can able to insert 1000s of records in staging table using `OracleBulkCopy`. I created 'Before Insert' trigger on table and tried oraclebulkcopy, But it is showing error

> "ORA-26086: direct path does not support triggers"

Is there solution for this??

Comment: From http://ora-26086.ora-code.com/ **Action: Disable the triggers on the table and try again.**

Comment: Its needed. I can not disable triggers. any other solution?